# When asking for advice, How can I make my questions more clear?

Tags: discussion, users

I have asked a few questions already, and I get at least 1 comment saying that I was unclear, or didn't provide enough information. I'm very new to ubuntu, and I'm hoping to learn and get better, and I understand most Linux users are more advanced and don't want to deal with people who don't know anything. So what can I do to make my questions have more depth to them so people feel like they can help me?

Comment: I don't think it is because a person is new of itself (I am new).  The biggest problem I see is *not enough detail* in questions.  Saying "my pc said there was a problem" or "and then it didn't work" is not going to result in good answers. Specific details of problems, error messages, etc go a long way.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/, http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: You can start by linking the questions you posted so we can have a look!

Answer (score 6):

If people feel they need more information to answer something, they'll tell you. Unless it's a really obvious omission (you have a graphics issue and you haven't said what your graphics card is), people *should* be explicitly stating what they would want to see.

From what I can see of your questions, this is exactly what has happened. People have asked for specific details. They expect you to **edit your question**. We don't expect new users to know what's relevant, which is why users can update their questions.

In many cases you haven't done this yet. If you don't understand what it is they're asking for, reply to them in the comments and say what you're struggling with but please don't ignore them. They are trying to help.

Comment: Also the reputed members write the commands in comments (which are required to get details of the problem) for new users to help them out.